# Как сделать регулярное выражение, чтоб не мог вводить буквы на любом языке кроме русского и английского?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

можно ввести

- русские буквы
- английские
- цифры
- все символы по типу !"№;%: и т.д без их перечисления

не мог вводить:

- буквы других языков

Comment: А это  русский, английский или символы? 
А это «ᕕ( ᐛ )ᕗ»?

Comment: ё или ë? Или Cafè?

Comment: В общем, зачем вам это нужно? Может есть более правильный путь…

Comment: Какой у вас язык? Возможно, можно будет использовать специфические возможности языка для решения проблемы.

Comment: `[\p{Cyrillic}\p{Latin}\p{S}\p{P}\p{N}]` все зависит от библиотеки regex и прочих мелких условий https://regex101.com/r/DuxlTY/1

Answer (score 2):

Без перечисления не получится. Вы либо перечисляете символы которые можно выводить (в том числе диапазон), либо перечисляете те символы, которые нельзя выводить. Нет универсального способа определить, является ли символ `сиволом по типу  !"№;%` или `символом "другого алфавита"`, поэтому регулярное выражение никогда не узнает, можно ли выводить символ. Напишите фильтр по кириллическим и латинским символам, а также перечислите те символы, которые вы хотите разрешить.